# Recently created philosophical ideas

Tags: history-of-philosophy

I've been reading about a lot of different types of philosophies, religions, ways of thinking etc. I was wondering what are the most recently created philosophical ways of looking at the universe? Where can one find out about new cutting edge ideas?

Example: Before we had Marxism, Communism, Zen, Christianity etc. Now X,Y, and Z have been created building on and evolving the ideas of A,B,C.

Everything I read about are ideas that were created a long time ago. What is new and updated?

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.SE. "new" and "updated" are pretty different categories. Also, can you explain a bit more why you're specifically interested in new ideas? (my non-answer version is that *many ideas* are thought either anew or originally every day, but few of these stand up to even the slightest degree of scrutiny or get a following that keeps them in our social consciousness).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the welcoming. My main interest in new ideas comes from a couple different angles. One is that many ideas that I find are just rehashed or slightly altered versions. The other is that I lack a firm understanding of the philosophical world of study and how ideas are constructed and formalized. I also don't want to waste to much time learning about old ideas that have already been "disproved" or re-examined.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a significant idea in philosophy younger than a few centuries. If you look carefully you'll see that nearly all ideas have been disproved or refuted, and I feel your approach of avoiding learning about them is a good one,. albeit it is a good idea to know ones enemy and understand what doesn't work before moving on to what does.

Answer (score 4):

Some very quick arrows:

1. Speculative realism (Meillassoux)
2. Object oriented ontology (Harman)
3. Non-philosophy (Laruelle)
4. Geotraumatics (Negarestani)
5. Neo-reaction (Land)
6. Accelerationism (Srnicek/Williams)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there are 10,000s of philosophers doing original research. They vary in terms of their originality, esteem, etc., as well as how history will judge these qualities (-- your guess is as good as mine).

I was recommended Passmore's Recent Philosophers, a little analytic philosopher primer, published in the mid 80s. I like e.g. [Goodman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Goodman). More contemporary thinkers are, as Joseph says, about, but will only appear in popular / 1st year philosophy as a footnote.

If you're intrigued about philosophical *movements*, camps, trends, or trailblazers, then Joseph's answer would be useful place to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to read through this, on the 50 most influential living philosophers https://thebestschools.org/features/most-influential-living-philosophers/ I certainly found it interesting for finding recent thinkers on the topics that interest me